# Recover SQL code from MAMP's phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mamp

So, I'm a total moron as of late and deleted all of my tables from localhost thinking it was my remote server by accident. I was mistakenly in the wrong tab of my browser. Is there anyway to retrieve my old SQL code to rewrite all of the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHPMyAdmin` won't store backups for your data unless there was a new setting for that? If you have deleted the data even mistakenly and there is no backup then chances of finding it back are very very very dim. `PhpMyAdmin` wont be able to give it back to you, to answer your question.

Comment: If this helps at all, I regularly connect to my DB via a third party app called SQL pro.